# MFC SysLink Control

Tags: c++, mfc

when ever am adding MFC `SysLink Control` to my application , it forces the application to close , am using VC++ 11 , and am just dragging a syslink control tool to my dialog box, any clue why it forces the app to close?

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem. SysLink requires Common Control 6.0 defined in the manifest. I solved it by adding the following line in the project

```
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

Answer (score -1):

You must set `Generate manifest=yes` in the `properties-linker-manifest` files.